# add different data at the end of different lines in a file

Tags: csv, python-3.x, numpy, append

I have a txt file with the following structure:

[image: original.txt file]

I also want to add to the end of each long line, the data (after the comma) of the short lines above them, without the description (STN_NO, STN_ID, INST_HT), like this:

[image: manipulatetd.txt file]

Is it possible? Any ideas?

P.S. I am using Python Version 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a simpler (albeit longer) solution that does not involve regex.

```
f = open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    if 'STN_NO' in line:
        stn_no = line.split(',')[-1]
        print(line)
    elif 'STN_ID' in line:
        stn_id = line.split(',')[-1]
        print(line)
    elif 'INST_HT' in line:
        inst_ht = line.split(',')[-1]
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line[:-1] + ',' + stn_no + ',' + stn_id + ',' + inst_ht)
```

Note that this puts the semicolon from the `INST_HT` line back at the end of every long line. If not desired, it can be removed with `inst_ht[:-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume this simplified version of the file in your image:

```
STN_NO, 41943043
STN_ID, KAST
INST_HT, 1.01500;
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
STN_NO, 41943062
STN_ID, S2
INST_HT, 0.75;
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
STN_NO, 123456
STN_ID, XXX
INST_HT, 0.99;
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

You can use a regex to capture the pattern in blocks and combine:

```
import re

pat=re.compile(r'^STN_NO,\s+([^\n]+)$\s*^STN_ID,\s+([^\n]+)$\s*^INST_HT,\s+([^;]+);\s*(.*?)(?=^STN_NO|\Z)', re.S | re.M)

with open(fn) as f:
    txt=f.read()

for mg in pat.finditer(txt):
    for line in mg.group(4).splitlines():
        print(line+','+','.join([mg.group(1), mg.group(2), mg.group(3)]))
```

Prints:

```
Line 1,41943043,KAST,1.01500
Line 2,41943043,KAST,1.01500
Line 3,41943043,KAST,1.01500
Line 4,41943062,S2,0.75
Line 5,41943062,S2,0.75
Line 6,41943062,S2,0.75
Line 7,123456,XXX,0.99
Line 8,123456,XXX,0.99
Line 9,123456,XXX,0.99
```

If your file is bigger than what will fit in memory, use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) to virtualize.